# Beaver Themer archive page pagination not working

Tags: wordpress

When creating a Beaver Builder/Beaver Themer layout for archive pages (including those with custom post types and custom taxonomies) why does clicking on page 2 lead to a 404 page saying, "Oops, this article couldn't be found! Something went wrong."?

Answer (score 1):

On Beaver Themer archive layouts, your posts lists or content grid module needs to be set to "Main Query", not "Custom Query". If you select "Custom Query", there could be a pagination conflict.

When selecting "Main Query", the issue is you're not given a posts per page option in the module. This is handled by WordPress by default under `Settings -> Reading -> Blog pages show at most`.

If you go to `https://example.com/your-archive-page/page/2`, WordPress goes by the default posts per page and total number of posts in the archive to calculate pagination. If you select "Custom Query" and use custom filtering options, WordPress will ignore these. If you have 10 posts in total, and have 5 posts per page, and try to go to page 3, WordPress won't find the posts and it will display a 404 error.

If your archive layout is for a custom taxonomy, you can modify the custom taxonomy's posts per page with this code using the [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin:

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'limit_custom_taxonomy_posts_per_page');

function limit_custom_taxonomy_posts_per_page($query) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax('your_custom_taxonomy_here')) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }
}
```

See [`pre_get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) for more options.